# Get the index of the minimium N elements of a list in Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to get the index of the minimum N elements of a list. It would be great if I can get that output on another list.

For example:

```
[1, 1, 10, 5, 3, 5]
output = [0, 1]

[10, 5, 12, 5, 0, 10]
output = [4]

[9, 2, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2]
output = [1, 3, 6]

[10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
output = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I know `.index` returns the first index for the minimum value in a list, but I don't know how to return all the indexes for the minimum value when it occurs more than once.

Comment: unaccept my answer and accept wim's...

Comment: it's all about the performance. But mine also works..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
>>> L = [9, 2, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2]
>>> minL = min(L)
>>> [i for i, x in enumerate(L) if x == minL]
[1, 3, 6]
```

Currently, the other solutions *will* call `min` during the iteration, resulting in a poor and unnecessary *O(n^2)* complexity.

---

Edit for Kasra:  evidence of n^2 complexity of the naive solution:

```
>>> L1000 = [randint(0, 100) for _ in xrange(1000)]
>>> L2000 = [randint(0, 100) for _ in xrange(2000)]
>>> L3000 = [randint(0, 100) for _ in xrange(3000)]
>>> L4000 = [randint(0, 100) for _ in xrange(4000)]
>>> L5000 = [randint(0, 100) for _ in xrange(5000)]
>>> timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(L1000) if x == min(L1000)]
10 loops, best of 3: 18.8 ms per loop
>>> timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(L2000) if x == min(L2000)]
10 loops, best of 3: 73.6 ms per loop
>>> timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(L3000) if x == min(L3000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 166 ms per loop
>>> timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(L4000) if x == min(L4000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 294 ms per loop
>>> timeit [i for i, x in enumerate(L5000) if x == min(L5000)]
1 loops, best of 3: 457 ms per loop
```

Comment: if `if x == min(L)` did it call in every iteration ?

Comment: This is much faster for a standard lib answer, +1. I added a large list benchmark to my answer if you're interested :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) as well with [`.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html), which is great for larger lists (*larger as in thousands or more elements*).

```
import numpy as np
mylist = [1, 1, 10, 5, 1, 5]
minL = min(mylist)
numparray = np.array(mylist)
print(list( np.where(numparray == minL)[0]))
```

**Outputs:**

```
[0, 1, 4]
```

---

## Simple benchmark:

**[Wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29677739/4686625):**

```
>>>setup = '''
L = [9, 2, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2] * 5000
minL = min(L)
'''
>>> print (min(timeit.Timer(
            '[i for i, x in enumerate(L) if x == minL]', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
3.218847516924143
```

**[Donkey Kong's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29678236/4686625):**

```
>>> setup = '''
import numpy as np
mylist = [9, 2, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2] * 5000
minL = min(mylist)
numparray = np.array(mylist)
'''
>>> print (min(timeit.Timer(
          'list( np.where(numparray == minL)[0])', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000)))
1.4015787709504366
```

For a 35000 element list, the NumPy solution is more than twice as fast. For small lists however, Wim's answer is enough.

Also, a small benchmark to show the crushing `O(n^2)` time complexity of calling `min` *inside* a list comprehension (*700 element list*):

```
>>> setup = '''
L = [9, 2, 8, 2, 3, 4, 2] * 100
'''
>>> print (min(timeit.Timer(
           '[i for i,j in enumerate(L) if j == min(L)]', setup=setup).repeat(7, 1000))) 
7.43799185753
```

Comment: ＋1 numpy is the best way to do this, if you have it available

Comment: You could also try using `numpy.min` instead of `min`, but the difference on my machine is minimal.

Comment: @dshepherd Yeah, I think the efficiency difference is negligible, considering I have a built-in list anyways.